# Removing comma in in-text citation, Biblatex (Bath style)

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

I have been struggling to change my in-text citation from:

> (Pirone  and  Tykot,  2017: 80)

To

> (Pirone and Tykot 2017: 80 )

I am trying to **remove the comma between the authors and date** for which I might need help with.

I am using for now Biblatex, using natbib commands and the style Bath:

```
   \usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
    \AtBeginBibliography{\let\mkbibnamefamily\textsc} %Last name in Upper Case in reference list
    \addbibresource{references.bib}
```

I have found a topic similar to this one and I have tried the proposed solution to add  `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}` as in:

```
\usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1,natbib=true]{biblatex}
    \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

    \renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1} %remove p.
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %remove p.
    \AtBeginBibliography{\let\mkbibnamefamily\textsc} %Last name in Upper Case in reference list
    \addbibresource{references.bib}
```

But I still get the comma between author and date when I compile:

> (Pirone  and  Tykot,  2017: 80)

I am not managing to identify the problem and would like to try alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\DeclareDelimFormat` to redefine the delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=bath,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
% To remove comma everywhere:
%\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}   

\begin{filecontents}{temp.bib}
@book{temp1,
author = {John Doe},
title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet},
year= {2020}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Comma removed for citations in text: \parencite[80]{temp1}, \citep[80]{temp1}

Comma not removed for citations in footnote:\footcite[80]{temp1}\footnote{\cite[80]{temp1}.}

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks !